# Android WebView corrupt drawing after scrollTo()

Tags: android, scroll, webview, bitmap, draw

I am writing an app which I need a WebView to serve as a web rendering mechanism for an Android service.
So the WebView isn't ever attached to a window.
However I am able to generate snapshots of the pages without placing it into a view hierarchy by manually measuring and laying out the view (ViewGroup) and then drawing on it out to a Bitmap.

The problem is once I make a call on it to scrollTo() the view won't draw the parts of the page which were hidden before the scroll and crops it, something like this

[image: scrolled a bit along x and y axis as well]

The WebView is laid out long before the page load is requested using the following method

```
private void layout(
        @NonNull final WebView webView, final int targetWidth, final int targetHeight) {
    webView.measure(
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(targetWidth, View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST),
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(targetHeight, View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST));

    webView.layout(0, 0, targetWidth, targetHeight);
}
```

The bitmap is captured using the following code

```
private Bitmap capture(
        @NonNull final WebView webView) {
    webView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    webView.buildDrawingCache();

    final Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
            webView.getWidth(), webView.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    webView.draw(canvas);

    webView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

    return bitmap;
}
```

The overall procedure goes like this

```
layout(mWebView, maxWidth, maxHeight);
// page is loaded
mWebView.scrollTo(...);
// here I've tried number of things like mWebView.invalidate(), mWebView.requestLayout() or mWebView.refreshDrawableState()
final Bitmap bitmap = capture(mWebView);
```

IMPORTANT: when I load the page within a WebView that is normally attached to a window within an activity the WebView gets scrolled where I want it and the page is displayed nicely.

What is the difference ? How is this different to what android does to the WebView when it is attached to a window of an activity ?

Comment: I'm sure that `WebView` employs optimizations where it doesn't redraw itself if it detects that it's not attached to a window. Have you tried calling `invalidate()` on the WebView? Perhaps that might force a full redraw...

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, I have.
I have tried requestLayout() as well as doing this after a short (~1s) timeout after page is loaded.

Comment: I've looked, it's hard to understand exactly what is going over there (WebView, WebViewChromium, etc.), but I can tell you that some drawing/scrolling functionality requires the WebView to run on UI thread / be attached to view hierarchy. In addition, seems like `View.invalidate()` [will skip if not visible](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/view/View.java#View.skipInvalidate%28%29)

Comment: This works for regular case. It is not working when I adjust webview scroll position only.

Answer (score 1):

I've finally found a root cause for this.
My mechanism which created the bitmap relied on the fact that the WebView has the drawing cache enabled and draws itself on my canvas.

The drawing cache would be enabled but it was never updated after the scroll change because only the view state changed.

It appears that since I am enabling HW acceleration for the view rendering all I need to do is to enable the drawing cache and just USE IT whenever I need a new bitmap (I don't even need to invalidate the view for the purpose) after I set the scrolling position.

So the solution would be something like:

```
public void init() {
    mWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
    mWebView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    // (layout the view)
}

public void capture(...) {
    mWebView.scrollTo(...);
    final Bitmap capturedBitmap = mWebView.getDrawingCache();
    // do sth with the bitmap
    // ...
}
```

So it is all much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
mWebView.scrollTo(...);

webView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
webView.buildDrawingCache();//write these lines before posting the capture event

new Handler.post(){
    new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            final Bitmap bitmap = capture(mWebView);
        }
    }
}
```

It might solve your issue ... :-)

Comment: Thanks for the reply however this did not help.